# How to apply CSS style to a Sibling Label field of a Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Based on this HTML code below, the Div with classes `iradio_square-green checked` I need to somehow make the `<label>` above it apply a certain CSS style to that Label when that class `checked` exist on the Div below the Label.

```
<label for="indoor-backing-radio-2">
    <span>Clear Backing</span>
</label><br>

<div class="iradio_square-green checked" style="position: relative;">
    // other code
</div>
```

So when the Div has a class of `checked` then the `<label>` field immediately above that Div will need to apply a style of `border: 4px solid #559A08;` to the `<label>`.

I'm not sure if this can be done with just CSS or if JavaScript is required?  In either case I could use a little help in getting this functionality.  Once I get it working, it will apply to hundreds of fields.  Thanks for any help

Comment: I think it's impossible with just CSS, looks like CSS' looking/scanning direction is always from top to bottom (downward), upward direction is not supported. That's why you may want to place the `div` before the `label` in HTML code but change some style to make `div` after the `label` visually.

Comment: How are you adding the 'checked' class to the `div`?

Comment: @louisbros of course using script, that's a technique to change the element style quickly with all the styles predefined.

Comment: Do you use these labels (labels and inputs) in a form context as well? Otherwise it would not be semantic.

Comment: @KingKing yes I suspected that. So why not add some kind of 'border' class to the previous sibling of the `div` at the same time?

Comment: when you add `checked` class to `div` add some class to `label` as well. and apply the style to `class` of that `label`.

Comment: @louisbros well, good point, however it really depends on the OP's context, I mean it's not still clear on how and when he gets reference to the `div`...

Comment: Can you please add the HTML where you added the inputs (radios or checkboxes) in your code?

Comment: @louisbros It is all generated from a script https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck

Comment: @jasondavis hey, based on that plugin I've provided a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [plugin](http://fronteed.com/iCheck/#demo) you're using provides an event called `ifToggled`. You could provide a callback for this event that toggles a 'checked' class on the corresponding label:

```
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');

$('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_polaris',
    radioClass: 'iradio_polaris'
});

$('input').on('ifToggled', function(event){

    // find the corresponding label of this input and toggle the class
    for(var j = 0;j < labels.length;j++){
        if(labels[j].htmlFor === event.currentTarget.id){
            $(labels[j]).toggleClass('checked');
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/t6uGU/).

Looking for the label this way means you don't need to rely on a specific order of DOM elements.

Comment: I had already come up with a solution but the project I am working on required me to have several different solutions for different sections to work, this is much better though since I can use this and have it work everywhere, thanks for taking the time to look into this, The ifToggled event is perfect

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .prev() JQuery method to reach the previous sibling.
https://api.jquery.com/prev/

You can use the .hasClass() method for checking if your div has the required class.
https://api.jquery.com/?s=hasclass

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The :checked pseudo class works with radio and checkbox inputs only. Using a checked class would only be necessary for IE8 and below. When you click the associated label the input will be set to checked is true.

The idea is you than style the label:

```
input:checked + label {
 // set a checked style
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QfNXL/8/

Comment: I think you misunderstood the OP, he means the `class="checked"` not `checked` attribute or `:checked` pseudo-class.

Comment: If the checked class is added to the div when the label and its associated input is set to checked true. He only needs to see if he can target the label with CSS like in my example for instance or target the label with JS (DOM).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.iradio_square-green.checked').prev().prev('label').css({"border-color": "#559A08","border-width":"4px","border-style":"solid"});
```

This should work :)
demo : http://jsfiddle.net/rbtaw/3RTUt/

Answer (score 1):

remove that `<br>` tag and follow this code -- >

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".checked").prev("label").addClass( "myborderstyle" );

});
```

and write CSS styling for that class like this -- >

```
.myborderstyle{
    border: 4px solid #559A08;
}
```

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EyWPs/1/)

This one is much simpler and also semantically clean because it keeps the CSS styling part away from javascript and let css do the job. It will just add the styling to whichever label is before the class `checked` 
**Note:** If you want to specifically target `checked` class which also has the `iradio_square-green` class then you must use `$(".iradio_square-green.checked")`

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, I'd suggest something similar to the following:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
    var that = this,
        state = that.checked;
    // this *adds* the 'checked' class-name when
    // the radio is checked (I'm assuming that
    // something similar happens somewhere in your code):
    $(that).closest('div').toggleClass('checked', state);

    // selects the label for the affected radio and
    // adds, or removes, the 'radioChecked' class
    // if the radio is, or is not, checked:
    $('label[for="' + that.id + '"]').toggleClass('radioChecked', state)
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FkrWt/).

More specifically-useful answers would be possible if we knew the precise HTML structure you're using, and the relevant already-working JavaScript you're using.

References:

- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 1):

The straight answer is that you can't do exactly that with CSS only because there isn't a predecessor selector you can use.

However, if you can afford to swap the elements, then there is an elegant solution because there is an immediate successor selector you can use ("+").

```
.iradio_square-green.checked + [for=indoor-backing-radio-2] {
    border: 4px solid #559A08;
}
```

See the working code here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKkht/?editors=110

There is even a (not necessarily immediate) successor selector ("~") that you can use to target successors further away. For instance, you could do this

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lkwEK/?editors=110

Having said that the HTML in your example is a bit odd, maybe it makes sense in context but what it seems is that you are associating the label to a radio button elsewhere but it's a div that controls the "checked" state. This is not semantic and it's wasteful because you can have much more elegant solutions with proper form elements.

This example is a pure CSS solution for a common problem that could be what you need to solve.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yladt/?editors=111

(This example is an eyesore but couple it with good visual design and the results are quite slick and powerful)

Of course, if you want to use JS everything is possible.